# Vue router.push and router.replace resulting in circular redirect

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

Vue Component A is designed so that if an array's length is greater 1 it displays a list of links to each item in the array. Otherwise the component redirects to the to single link (Component B).

This is in Component A:

```
  setup(props) {
                const router = useRouter();
                if (props.arrayGroup.arrayItems.length == 1) {
                    router.replace(props.arrayGroup.url)
            
                }
```

The issue is that upon redirect to Page B if the user presses the browser back button the page goes back to Page A- which then evaluates the setup hook and redirects again to Page B. Basically creating a redirect loop.

The react router docs seem to indicate that this should be solved by using react.replace() but it did not work in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question for anyone else in a similar situation in the future:

Make sure you're calling router.replace() like this:  `router.replace({ path: props.arrayGroup.url })`